# Static map initializer function error

Tags: c++, initialization, static-members

I get the following base error:

> 1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(163): error C2436: 'second' : member function or nested class in constructor initializer list

As well as a lot of sub-errors there - I have no idea at all where to look or what goes wrong. (I know what functions it is about, but I'm staring myself blind on why it doesn't work)

The header part:

```
typedef void *DuplicateFn(pTree&, const pTree&); 
enum DuplicateTy {
    SKIP,
    OVERWRITE,
    ASK
};
typedef std::map<DuplicateTy, DuplicateFn> DuplicateMapTy;

static const DuplicateMapTy DuplicateFns;
static DuplicateMapTy DuplicateFns_INIT();
```

detail namespace:

```
namespace detail {
    void OverWriteFn(GMProject::pTree& tOut, const GMProject::pTree& tIn);
    void AskFn(GMProject::pTree&  tOut, const GMProject::pTree& tIn);
}
```

The source part:

```
GMProject::DuplicateMapTy GMProject::DuplicateFns_INIT() {
    DuplicateMapTy tmp;
    auto p(std::make_pair(GMProject::OVERWRITE, &detail::OverWriteFn));
    tmp.insert(p); //offending line
    return tmp;
}
const GMProject::DuplicateMapTy GMProject::DuplicateFns(GMProject::DuplicateFns_INIT());
```

As said I'm staring myself blind on this, why can't I insert that pair into the map? I'm simply inserting a function pointer & an enum?

Comment: Your function typedef may be wrong. Try: typedef `void (*DuplicateFn)(pTree&, const pTree&);`

Comment: It looks like something goes wrong with the instantiation of std::map<...> template. Does the compiler point to the template constructor of std::map<>?

Comment: @visitor *doh*, it sure has to be such a trivial problem. Though trivial - I've learned that you have to put braces around the typedef function-pointer. However why? - What do I say without braces? (PS: put it in an answer ><)

Comment: @paul23: In your code, the compiler thinks you are defining a typedef for `void*`. And weird things happen.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I don't like the line:

```
auto p(std::make_pair(GMProject::OVERWRITE, &detail::OverWriteFn));
```

Are you using VS 2010? You can hover the variable name (`p`) and see which type `auto` has deduced.

Also, have you tried:

```
 tmp.insert(std::make_pair(GMProject::OVERWRITE, &detail::OverWriteFn));
```

Or

```
tmp.insert(std::pair(GMProject::OVERWRITE, &detail::OverWriteFn));
```

?